# {InternalError}ERROR: Assert false - Invalid type: 705

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, pygresql

based on https://pygresql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contents/pg/adaptation.html

> sql = "SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE login = %s AND passwd = %s"

> db.query_formatted(sql, (login, passwd)).getresult()[0]

I reused this snippet of code to try to use the library SQL replacement as shown in this example:

```
import pg

pg.DB(*credentials)

sql = "select %s, %s from my.table limit 10"
c.query_formatted(sql, ("id", "event_time")).getresult()[0]
```

and trying to query a Redshift table.

Unfortunately I get this error message

```
{InternalError}ERROR:  Assert
DETAIL:  
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Assert
  code:      1000
  context:   false - Invalid type: 705
  query:     9876543
  location:  tbl_trans.hpp:923
  process:   padbmaster [pid=6543]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

which I really have no idea how to interpret.

I also tried to query with another client

```
select *
from stl_error
where pid = 6543;
```

but all I get is:

```
userid,process,recordtime,pid,errcode,file,linenum,context,error
100,padbmaster,2021-03-01 12:00:00,6543,1000,/home/ec2-user/padb/src/sys/tbl_trans.hpp,923,Assert,false - Invalid type: 705
```

Anyone knows what's the problem here? Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Two problems here:

1. PyGreSQL does not officially support Redshift.
   Though it may work, PyGreSQL was made for PostgreSQL only.
   It doesn't contain any special provisions for Redshift and is only tested with PostgreSQL (the current version requires PostgreSQL 9 or newer).
2. The select list must be specified as literals specifying the columns: `select id, event_time from  ...` Query parameters are only used to insert values into queries.

Comment: thanks for your reply. To add more context, I'm using AWS Glue Python-shell Jobs which natively provide PyGreSQL and is unfortunate that it doesn't support Redshift :( In the documentation it even talks about connecting to Redshift via PyGreSQL https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-job-python.html

Comment: I don't know how compatible Redshift is with standard Postgres. The fact that it's mentioned in the AWS docs indicates that it seems to be compatible enough that it works to some extent. So you can give it a try. But again, use with Redshift is not officially supported or tested by the PyGres devs.